# C double holds 0 no matter what I input

Tags: c, double

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double a,b;
    scanf("%lf%lf",&a,&b);
    printf("%lf %lf",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

The result I'm getting from printf here is 0.000000 no matter the input. What should I do to remedy this? It seems it's some compiler or system related issue, but I have no idea what could it be.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me! See: http://ideone.com/Xkq1Hw

Comment: Can you please show your input? And what locale (language) is your OS using?

Comment: 1.1 2.2
is my input, and I'm compiling it on polish Windows 8

Comment: If [@Clifford](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27206259/2410359) does not work, try this shot in the dark: some weak compilers do not properly incorporate FP math unless some math is seen and Input/Output does not do it.  Try adding `printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",a,b,a+b);` to force some FP math.

Comment: What is the return value from `scanf()`?  If it is not 2, code should not even attempt `printf("%lf %lf",a,b);`.  At least initialize `a,b` to some thing interesting like 5.6 and 7.8 to see if `scanf()` is doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

`%lf` is not a valid format specifier. You should use `%f` for a `double`, or `%Lf` for `long double` (where supported).

Comment: `%lf` is only invalid in `printf` and only before C99.

Comment: in C99 and C11, `%lf` is same as `%f`

Comment: @Cubbi : OK, but for widest compatibility, %f is worth a try, since there are few other explanations from the information given.

Comment: I suspect you are correct as OP said "Windows 8" (OP really should have specified compiler, not OS) and _certain_ compilers there are not C99 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine on Ubuntu 64bit with gcc4.8.2

Please give more info about you compiler/arch/ etc..

Answer (score -1):

I think what you’re doing is to input a number with a `decimal point`(`,`)!

Something like this:

```
0,4565 0,345
```

But you have to use a `dot`(`.`)! Like this:

```
0.4565 0.345
```

Then it should work fine! There is no error/mistake in the program

Comment: Nope, using dots in my input

Comment: @Marcin It has to work fine! What is your input? Also which compiler do you use?

Comment: I'm using code::blocks 13.12. And input is just 1.1 and 2.2, nothing fancy. I keep getting zeros no matter what I type in, really. Might be worth mentioning I have the following flags set: -std=c99, -static, -Wall, -lm, -c.

Comment: Err I mean gcc compiler

Comment: This is an excerpt from my build log, since I just hit "build and run" button: 
mingw32-gcc.exe -std=c99 -static -Wall -lm  -c C:\...\test.c -o C:\...\test.o  
mingw32-g++.exe  -o C:\Users\Whitesheep\Desktop\Programy\test.exe C:\...\test.o

Comment: @Marcin That's really strange, Which OS are you using! Also  You need to ensure that the operating system creates threads with 8-byte stack alignment.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 with polish localization. What's worth mentioning is that substituting double with float and 'lf' with 'f' makes it run just fine, seems to be just double related issue..

Comment: @Marcin Are you sure your OS creates threads with 8-byte stack alignment and do you have to problem with double only in this program or general?

Comment: @ Rizier123 I have no idea how to check that, I'm currently working on finding that out, might be that's the case. And yeah, the problem seems to be persistant throughout all the programs.

Comment: @Marcin Does it work if you initialized the double variable with 1.1 and 2.2 can you print that? (So that you don't read in the variables with scanf)

Comment: No, if I initialize them with 1.1 and 2.2 they still read 0.000000 or -0.000000 when printed..

Comment: @Marcin What output do you get if you run this program here: http://ideone.com/v4CvkC ?

Comment: Size of int: 4bytes  Size of float: 4 bytes  Size of double: 8 bytes  Size of char: 1 byte

Comment: @Marcin That's really strange! I would guess that your OS not creates threads with 8 bytes.

Comment: @Marcin Maybe try it with another compiler so that your sure it's the OS.